# Assign objects inside class to variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, object, variables

Im looking to set certain objects inside a class to a variable so then I can retrieve the content of variable and display in DOM. For testing I had this function in my code:

```
    const height = window.instance._height
    
    function debugLogs() {
      console.log(height + 'from context menu')
    }
debugLogs()
```

This does not work as I get the following error from console:
[image]

For testing, i assign the class object to variable from the google dev console, and it works there. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong to make it work in my code? Thank you

[image]

Comment: What is `window.instance`? Where/when/how do you define it?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to access `window.instance._height` before `instance` is assigned to `window.instance`.

Comment: @ErnestoStifano window.instance is injected by a different javascript. I tried to assign window.instance to a variable first like this :

```const sdkDebug = window.instance
const height = sdkDebug._height

function debugLogs() {
  console.log(height + 'from context menu')
}

debugLogs()```

Comment: But i get this error from console https://i.ibb.co/4drymjD/Screen-Shot-2021-07-19-at-2-05-30-PM.png

Comment: You try to eat the pizza before it is made..... `window.instance` is not available when you read it so you need to make sure your script runs after window.instance is set.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access `window.instance` before it is defined/assigned.

Usually, in a single "synchronous" script, this is easy to debug and solve. If more scripts or modules are involved and the "global" scope is used to communicate (today this could be considered bad practice), then things can turn confused very fast. Especially if this scripts or modules are loaded "asynchronously" and a race condition is created.

To avoid this, global scope pollution should be completely avoided, a modular architecture should be adopted (using Webpack or other similar bundler) and callbacks/promises/events like APIs should be used for cross-module communication.

In your case, check the order of your `<script>` tags (also check that they don't have an `async` or `defer` attribute set). The script that defines/assigns `window.instance` must run first. If you can't do this, you will have to modify both scripts to "talk" to each other by using events (read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)) or other similar approach.

One last option would be to consider handle both cases inside your code (when `window.instance` is available and when it is not), however, this is not a good approach:

```js
function debugLogs() {
  if (window.instance) {
    const height = window.instance._height;
    console.log(height + 'from context menu');
  } else {
    console.log('Sorry, not available. Try again later.')
  }
}

debugLogs();
```